# Building a table using an array from user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have researched and researched and maybe I'm just missing it, but I'm a novice at javascript and still having trouble.  Basically, I need to build a table using data from an html form that creates an array.  I feel like I'm kinda close, but just can't get there.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flights = [];
            var miles = [];
 
            function getInfo() {
                flights.push(document.getElementById('flight').value); //add flight info element to array
                miles.push(document.getElementById('miles').value); //add miles info element to array
                document.getElementById('flight').value ='';
                document.getElementById('miles').value =''; //initial text box is blank
                
                
               }
               
             
               
              
               function disp(){
                
               var sum = 0;
               
               for (var i=0; i < miles.length; i++){
                sum = sum + miles[i];
                
               }
                
                var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
                document.body.appendChild(table);
                
                for(var i=0; i < flights.length; i++){
                 
                 var row = document.createElement("TR");
                 var flightCell = document.createElement("TD");
                 var milesCell = document.create Element("TD");
                 
                 document.createTextNode(flights[i]);
                 document.createTextNode(miles[i]);
                 
                 flightCell.appendChild(flights);
                 milesCell.appendChild(miles);
                 
                 row.appendChild(flights);
                 row.appendChild(miles);
                 
                 table.appendChild(row);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

```css
<style>
td
{border-left:1px solid black;
border-top:1px solid black;}
table
{border-right:1px solid black;
border-bottom:1px solid black;}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
        <title>array form test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        Flight #
      <input type="text" id="flight" /> 
      Miles Flown 
      <input type="text" id="miles" />
        <br />
      <input type="button" value="Add Flight Info"     onclick="getInfo();disp()" />
        <br />
        





    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You did not ask any question... What is the problem ?

Comment: Not on a QA format. Please, edit your question

Answer (score 1):

I often use the following `tableMaker` function to generate table HTML. So the below code will generate a table for you. The generic `tableMaker` function takes an array of an object or an array of multiple objects provided in the first argument. All objects should have same keys (properties) since these keys are used to create the table header (if the second argument is set to true) and the values are used to create each row. It will return an HTML table text.

```js
var tableMaker = (o,h) => {var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
                           rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                           : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                           rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
                           return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
                           };
        myCars = [{Pos: 1, Make: "Toyota"}, {Pos: 2, Make: "Volvo"}, {Pos: 3, Make: "BMW"}, {Pos: 4, Make: "Mercedes"}] ,
         table = tableMaker(myCars,true); // if second argument provided as truthy then headers generated
document.write(table);
```