# Optimized plain JavaScript means to iterate over static HTML table, creating array of objects based on its row/columns

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Recently I was asked to write some plain ol JS, that would iterate over a static html table, and allow me to sort the data therein respectively to the column. The idea I have currently is something that loops over the rows, getting the cells data. But I feel there has to be something I am overlooking. I feel I can optimize what I have thus far even further. I'm not really big on loops in loops, and the person who asked me this question is convinced it's possible as well. But I'm a little stumped thinking I can whittle it down further.

which what I have thus far is.

```
let table = document.getElementById( "table" );
let arr = [];
for(let i=1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    for(let j=0; j < table.rows[j].cells.length; j++) {
     obj[j] = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
  }
  arr.push(obj);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Heres the HTML for reference:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555</td>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>963</td>
    <td>Christy</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Bobby</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When I run 1,000 iterations of your code on that sample data, it takes around 20-30 milliseconds (so each call takes 20-30 microseconds). Why are you wasting time trying to optimize it? I assume the DOM access is the slowest part of the code, and you're only visiting each cell once (the minimum), so I don't imagine you can make this much faster even if you had a reason to.

Comment: One nitpick about the code: `obj` would be better as an array. (`let obj = []` and then optionally `obj.push(...)` instead of `obj[j] = ...`.)

Comment: @smarx thats generally what's been eating at me, I can't picture a real world need to optimize it further. But the fact that someone presented to me the possibility that it might be possible I've been nit picking over it in my head, and its just eating at me that I am stumped. I can see value in trimming it down to reduce byte overhead when uglified, and minimized, but beyond that, in a modern browser on a budget computer I still no issue otherwise

Comment: How is this table constructed in HTML in the first place? The raw data should be available either at the client or server side. I believe instead of accessing the DOM and playing with the HTML, it might be a better idea to keep a copy of the raw data at the client side and sort it accordingly to reconstruct the HTML table under a document fragment and replace the DOM table once. Here i have an example of generic Table Maker function that you may utilize to reconstruct a table from the raw data. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38627630/4543207

Comment: Undoubtedly there should be raw data, presumably via some rest like api of one shape form or another. With an object to generate this table originally from. However the challenge if you will, doesn't offer me that ability.

Comment: My initial thought is since it presented as statically available in html markup. Is to loop over the table initially, and create my own raw object from it at which point I can manipulate to my will from that point going forward

Answer (score 0):

You are using bubble sort, Use quick sort to make it even faster